# Why is Time Machine not pruning old backups?

Tags: time-machine, storage

Time Machine has stopped backing up for me "because there is insufficient free space on the backup disk."

[image: Time Machine was only able to complete 6% of the backup because there is insufficient free space on the backup disk.]

Only one snapshot is visible in the Finder; when I do right-click and select Get Info, it says it's using 674 GB. The drive has 2 TB with 50 GB free. However, when I do `sudo ls` on the volume, 2,000 snapshots are shown. Presumably those old snapshots are not getting pruned.

I'm running 12.6.3. Both volumes are formatted in APFS. The backup disk has one partition. The Mac has 1 TB of storage and the backup disk has 2 TB.

What's the cause of this discrepancy? And how do I get Time Machine to prune old backups as needed so that it can make new ones?

Comment: Thx for the new info and pls update your question also with the following: How much space do you have left on Mac’s 1 TB internal disk? Are there any disk other than the Mac’s internal disk being backed up to the 2 TB Time Machine disk? And what model is your Mac exactly?